# Изменить положение блока slick slider

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, slick.js

Доброго дня! Имеется карточка товара: [image: карточка товара]

панель слайдера расположена слева и вертикально. Делаю адаптив, нужно, чтобы слайдер стал горизонтальным и распологался снизу самой картинки. Попробовал сделать вот так:

```
  $('.product_slider__full').slick({
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    infinite: false,
    asNavFor: '.product_slider__thumbnails'
  });
  $('.product_slider__thumbnails').slick({
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    asNavFor: '.product_slider__full',
    focusOnSelect: true,
    draggable: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    infinite: false,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 767,
          settings: {
            vertical: false,
            verticalSwiping: false,
          }
        }
    ]
  });
```

результат получился вот такой:

[image: на адаптиве]

при попытке расположить блоки друг под другомвыходит вот так: 
[image: блок друг под другом]

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Расположить слайды в слайдере друг под другом? или сами слайдеры спозиционировать?

Comment: @l2banners вот этот блок со слайдами нужно поставить вниз, под основное изображение

Comment: У вас тогда скорее всего со стилями проблема, а не с конфигурцией слайдера.

Comment: Попрообуем, ковырял уже, просто думал может где-то есть параметр который отвечает за позиционирование слайдера. спасибо за ответы ))